# Undefined variable: query, when a form select sends only empty data (by choice)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, echo

I'm using a form and a receiving php pages to echo datas from a database, a form which proposes three select/menu actions, so on three different variables are used in the receiving page.

on the three select/menu, I like the top listed value to be empty and just display a "-" by using a code like this:

```
 <td>Alphabetical Company Name</td>
                          <td><select name="alpha" id="alpha">
                            <option value="">-</option>
                            <option value="a">A</option>
                            <option value="b">B</option>
                            <option value="c">C</option>
```

so when user open the form.php page, the first option/value selected in the box is just "-".

I builded the page who receive form's results to echo a table containing the selected data from the database.

Everything works fine BUT when I don't select any value on the three select/menu and click on submit button I get a : `notice: Undefined variable: query in ... Query was empty`

the `query` mentioned here reffers to : `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

I think that, if the three select/menu don't send any value, the `SELECT` process doesn't start so on the `$result = mysql_query($query)` doesnt receive any `query`,  but how do I fix that issue (in general) so that when a user keep the three select/menu without a value, the 'Undefined variable' warning/error does not happen ?

Sorry if my English is not clear and th question quite basic.

Comment: please can we have php and js code.?

Answer (score 0):

I think your form are not posting.

Comment: Well, if the 3 select/menus are kept "empty" by user, then I have a "if..." which echo a message 'please select at least one research's criteria'. I don't intend to developp this typ of answer, but some user might click without selecting any value, in that case I am 'just' trying to avoid the sql error notice.

Answer (score 0):

Normally before we send form data to server we have to validate the form fields which are mandatory at client side and server side.

We use `jQuery or JavaScript` at client side validations and here your using `PHP` So use this at server side to validate, which follows as

```
if($_GET) 
{

   if($_GET['alpha'] != NULL && !empty($_GET['alpha'])
   {

    // your code here
   }
}
else
{
    // Handle error here
}
```

> Replace $_GET method with whatever form method you have used in your form.

Answer (score -1):

I added this:

```
else if(!($req && $req2 && $req3 == NULL))
{
$query = NULL;
}
```

before the

`$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

and it works fine now, I just have the message "query was empty" which is self explenatory. Thanks to everybody for the time and answers